# Electron, new BrowserWindow load values

Tags: json, electron

I try load and pass from a json file the x,y position and width, height. Here is my code

```
const electron = require('electron')
const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron
var fs = require('fs');
var loadsttngs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('settings.json', 'utf8'));
console.log(loadsttngs.width);
let win

function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    x: loadsttngs.x,
    y: loadsttngs.y,
    width: loadsttngs.width,
    height: loadsttngs.height,
    frame: false})

  win.setMenu(null)
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)

  win.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
    //var bounds = win.getBounds();
    win = null
  })
}
```

the `console.log(loadsttngs.width);` return the right value, so there is no problem with reading the file but in the `new BrowserWindow` does not be used(like using some defaults values). If I write the values directly to `new BrowserWindow` works fine.

settings.json
{
    "x" : "50",
    "y" : "50",
    "width" : "1200",
    "height" : "200",
    "maximized": "false"
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your x and y values are strings not numbers.

Should be:

```
"x":50
```

Maximized is also a string not a Boolean.